# Adding a second argument to an lapply function

Tags: r, shiny

So I have a function `f(x1)` as part of a Shiny app, that is deployed like so:

```
y <- lapply(input$A, FUN = f)
```

Through the course of bug fixing, I have realized I need to add a second argument, making it `f(x1, x2)`, where x2 is a different `input`. But this code...

```
y <- lapply(input$A, FUN = f(..., input$B))
```

...gives me an error saying I am using `...` incorrectly. Can someone tells me what the proper syntax should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `lapply`, we can use `Map/mapply` for multiple arguments (assuming the length of 'input$A', 'input$B' are the same)

```
Map(f, input$A, input$B)
```

With `lapply`, an option is to loop over the sequence of input$A

```
lapply(seq_along(input$A), function(i) f(input$A[i], input$B[i]))
```

---

Or with `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(input$A, input$B, f)
```

Comment: Your `lapply(seq_along)` case was what I used, because my inputs A and B were of different lengths.